# How to add logback to gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, logback

I need to add logback to my project.
This is my test class:

```
public class Head implements Runnable {
    Thread trd;

    Head() {
        trd = new Thread(this);
        trd.start();
    }
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Head.class);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MDC.put("logName", "LOG_NAME");
        logger.warn("test1");
        logger.info("test2");
        logger.error("test");
        MDC.remove("logName");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String URL = "logback-test.xml";
        System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(URL));
        int count = 1;
        while(count<=3){
            Head head = new Head();
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my logback-test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

        <discriminator>
            <key>logName</key>
            <defaultValue>test</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${logName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>D:/tmp/${logName}.log</file>
                <append>false</append>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I have added following groovy dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.21'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.1.7'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.1.7'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-access', version: '1.1.7'
compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:1.8.9"
```

But when I try to run main method I get:

```
file:/D:/my_tests/build/resources/main/logback-test.xml
    Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
       Reported exception:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:59)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator$run.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:44)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferUtil.runGafferConfiguratorOn(GafferUtil.java:43)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:67)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
at com.aerlingus.uita.utils.Head.<clinit>(Head.java:20)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:                        org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 20 more
```

Could you help me to fix this?

Error after adding dependency `compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-backports-compat23', version: '2.3.5'`:

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
              Reported exception:
     java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.NestingType do not match. Expected -1 but got 2
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(MetaClassImpl.java:1413)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:234)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.NestingType.$INIT(NestedType.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:99)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.NestingType.<clinit>(NestedType.groovy)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:142)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedField.getProperty(CachedField.java:51)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1565)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3343)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.PropertyUtil.nestingType(PropertyUtil.groovy:32)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.PropertyUtil$nestingType.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ComponentDelegate.methodMissing(ComponentDelegate.groovy:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:830)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1128)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1081)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:723)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ComponentDelegate.invokeMethod(ComponentDelegate.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:407)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:348)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:8)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.ConfigurationDelegate.appender(ConfigurationDelegate.groovy:143)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MixinInstanceMetaMethod.invoke(MixinInstanceMetaMethod.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:313)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:7)
at Script1$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:77)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator$run.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:44)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferUtil.runGafferConfiguratorOn(GafferUtil.java:43)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:67)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
at com.aerlingus.uita.utils.Head.<clinit>(Head.java:20)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem stems from a Groovy version incompatibility. If your project allows, update your Groovy dependency to the newest version (currently, 2.4.6).

Otherwise, if your project requires Groovy 1.8.9, then you'll need to add a dependency on `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5`, as indicated in the [Gradle 2.3.5 release announcement](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/ANN-Groovy-2-3-5-released-and-upward-compatibility-tp5720557.html):

> [...] 
>   So we leveraged this version to add a new artifact, named `groovy-backports-compat23`. This artifact shouldn’t be necessary for most of you, but if you face an error like:
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
> ```
>
> in your project, then it means that a class has been compiled with Groovy 2.3+ but that you are trying to use it with an older version of Groovy. By adding this jar on classpath, you give a chance to your program to run. This may be particularily interesting for Gradle users that want to use a plugin built on Gradle 2+ on older versions of Gradle and face this error. Adding the following line to their build files should help:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>   // ...
>   dependencies {
>     classpath 'some plugin build on gradle 2'
>     classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Note that for now, this jar only contains the `ShortTypeHandlingClass`. Future versions may include more.
>   [...]

Comment: Thank you, I have add this dependency, but now I got another error: "the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.NestingType do not match. Expected -1 but got 2". Full log is in updated question

Comment: Do you actually need that specific version of groovy? Or can you update that dependency to the latest version (2.4.6) without problems? If so, you'd be able to remove this `compat` dependency.

Comment: It appears that old version is not required, there is no errors now. But I can't understand why logs are not saved into file: D:/tmp/LOG_NAME

Comment: I'm glad your runtime problem is resolved. The other issue is a different question :)